# squashfs file can be removed?

Tags: linux, embedded

I have a PC with embedded Tiny Core Linux 4.0.2 and a SD memory card of 1GB. The problem is that sda1 is a 100% full and I found a file that is 700 Mb. The file is `base.squashfs`, can i remove it??
I have read that is a file that is used by live cd, and booting from usb...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the 'base.squashfs' contains the actual system image you are running. Removing it may be equal to removing your operating system.

Comment: Thanks for the help, at the end were data from a previous operating system, so I deleted it and all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

[SquashFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) is a kind of (read-only) filesystem.  It allows compression and efficient storage of files, so it's often used as a container for live Linux distros, although 700MB sounds like a lot for Tiny Core Linux.

You can check the contents by mounting it, or you can just list the contents with `unsquashfs -l`, although if does contain a full Linux system, then the file listing may be too much to wade through.

If it is a Linux system, it might contain a file with a name like `/etc/...-release`, which generally contains information that identifies which distribution of Linux it is.